# prolog not all the same

Tags: prolog, logic

Hi I am new to prolog and I want to know how to express "not all the same" logically in prolog.

for example, if I have a function `valid(A, B, C, D)` that takes numbers as input and requires A B C D are not all the same, how do I state it?

I tried `valid(A, B, C, D) :- not(A == B == C == D).` It seems not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`==/2` is a binary predicate, `'=='(X,Y)`, that will succeed or fail depending upon whether `X` and `Y` are bound to the same value. So you can't "cascade" them like `A == B == C` as it would be a syntax error.

What you can do is individual pairs. This would be an adequate test to tell if any one of `A`, `B`, `C` or `D` are different (*i.e.*, they are "not all the same"):

```
valid(A, B, C, D) :-
    \+ (A == B, A == C, A == D).
```

You could generalize this to a list of numbers, [A,B,C,...]:

```
valid([X|T]) :- \+ maplist(==(X), T).
```

And get:

```
| ?- valid([a,a,a,a]).

no
| ?- valid([a,a,a,b]).

yes
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Check out the question "[different/2 - does a pure, determinate definition exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863784/different-2-does-a-pure-determinate-definition-exist)":

Multiple answers ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31306332/4609915)) manage to combine efficiency and [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity), which makes 
the code I wrote in *this* answer obsolete. The old code is still available at the end of this answer... but better ways have been found!

---

Use the builtin predicate `dif/2` for *safely* expressing term inequality! For details, see [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif).

With `dif/2` and `member/2` you could implement `valid/4` like this:

```
valid(A,B,C,D) :- 
   dif(X,Y),
   member(X,[A,B,C,D]),
   member(Y,[A,B,C,D]).
```